# How can I select all creased edges with specific weight at once, can be with python

Tags: python, selection-tools

[image: how to select edges by crease weight]

Technically simple thing, how can I check for exact crease weight edges and then select only them? Like only that one edge on the cube ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK There isn't a command for this, but here is a simple script which selects all *Edge Creases* with values above `0.5`:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

for e in me.edges:
    if e.crease > 0.5:
        e.select = True
        print (e.crease)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

---

*Bmesh module* solution (avoids toggling into *Object Mode*):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
cr = bm.edges.layers.crease.verify()

me.show_edge_crease = True

for e in bm.edges:
    if (e[cr] > 0.5):
        e.select = True
        print(e[cr])

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, False, False)
```

Answer (score 9):

1. Select a creased edge.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>> *Select Similar*
3. Crease.

It will add to the selection other edges with similar crease value. (Similar means 0.01 tolerance)

You can view and edit the selected crease value from the properties panel (toggled with <kbd>N</kbd>) on the Transform group.

[image: crease selection and value]

Comment: Ah, perfect! God bless you! Just what I was looking for! :)