# Old "select all creased edges" script does not work in 4.0. How do I fix?

Tags: python

> [How can I select all creased edges with specific weight at once, can be with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/how-can-i-select-all-creased-edges-with-specific-weight-at-once-can-be-with-pyt)

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

for e in me.edges:
    if e.crease > 0.5:
        e.select = True
        print (e.crease)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

This script works fine till 3.6, but not 4.0.

4.0 say, "mesh edge does not have 'crease' in line `if e.crease > 0.5:`".

Is something changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change in the handling of Bevel weight and Creases in 4.0

I faced the same issue today and here is the solution in my case, but not sure how it would work for your specific problem:
[Displaying and changing selected edges Mean Crease in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305134/displaying-and-changing-selected-edges-mean-crease-in-python)

Perhaps in your case simply add the line `crease = bm.edges.layers.float.get('crease_edge', None) if bpy.app.version >= (4,0,0) else bm.edges.layers.crease.active`

You can find more info on the changes for Python in 4.0:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/4.0/Python_API